# Setting state inside React functional setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is one allowed to call a `setState` inside the function passed into `setState`. for instance im trying to check for errors in user input and im calling the error checker function inside the `setInpuForm`, I know I can call the `checkerror()` from outside the `setInputForm` i.e inside the change handler, but out of curiosity, i decided to try it this way. But I discovered after typing the first character into the input field no changes but from the second entry up wards,its displayed. When i ran this it worked, the issue is that the very first time the input changed, the value was not updated but subsequently it worked

```
const errorChecker = (inputValue, element)=>{
    //check for password error
    if (element==='password') {
    if (inputValue.length<=6) {
        console.log('function error checker called')
        setInputForm((form)=>{
            console.log('after error check')
            console.log(form.password.value)
            return {
                ...form,
                [element]: {
                    ...form[element],
                    error: 'Password can not be less than 6'
                }
            }
        })
    }   else {
        setInputForm((form) => {
            return {
                ...form,
                [element]: {
                    ...form[element],
                    error: ''
                }
            }

        })
    }
}}

<Input 
    key={inputForm[it].label} 
    changed={(event) => {
        const val = event.target.value 
        
        setInputForm((form)=>{
          console.log(form.password.value)
          console.log('before error check')
          errorChecker(val, it) 
          console.log('from set valuie')
          
          return {
            ...form,
            [it]: {
              ...form[it],
              value: val
            }
          } 
        })                            
    }}
```

Comment: Calling the errorChecker function (which itself includes a call to setInputForm) within the callback passed to setInputForm is a bad idea. At best, you'll trigger a ton of useless renders, and at worst you'll be looking at a ton of difficult-to-find bugs - and that's if this code even runs! Why not have the errorChecker function validate the form elements and return a boolean; if the boolean is true, set the new state, otherwise handle telling the user that their input is invalid?

Comment: setState is async function also,you should add second state (example) const [error,setError]= usestate(false); and handle errors with that second one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are calling two `setState` functions one after another, both of which rely on the `previousState` value. `setState` as you may know is not synchronous, and needs some time to finish its execution. In the meantime what you would be using in your `errorChecker` function would be the last state registered.

In order to avoid this, in a `class` based component you would usually include a callback function on your `this.setState` function. In a `functional` component you cannot do that. Instead you can use `useEffect` in order to detect changes to a certain `state`, and trigger a function like `errorChecker` based on those changes.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (inputForm[it].value !== "") {
    errorChecker(inputForm[it].value, inputForm[it]);
  }
}, [inputForm[it].value);
```

Comment: I understand that setState is asynchronous, thanks. But even if it is asynchronus, the setState function on the onChange handler fires, then it sees the function checkError(), here again there is another setInputForm (which depends on initial state), but then goes futher and sees return {}, which should then update the current value to event.target.value. At least thats what i thhink should happen.

Comment: @AmasaAbubakar Actually not, as far as I know. When the execution encounters the function `errorChecker` it starts executing that function until the end (synchronously) and then moves on to the other instructions (e.g. console.log(),  return {}). This is because your `errorChecker` is not async. Even if it was, and the execution continued after starting to execute the function, there would be no way to determine if return happens before the `errorChecker` finishes executing, so you cannot tell if `errorChecker` is using the updated `inputForm` value or not.

Comment: I see. But the concern im having is that When i ran this (the code in the question) it worked, the issue is that the very first time the input changed, the value was not updated but subsequently the value was updated.

Comment: @AmasaAbubakar As I mentioned in my answer, this behaviour is encountered  because you are using the state before it is updated. So the results are usually one step behind.